# ModuleNotFoundError - Cannot install OpenCV for Python 3 on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, opencv, terminal

I am having some trouble downloading and importing the `OpenCV` library. In my Terminal, I executed

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

and I got the following response:

```
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.4.0.42)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.18.5)
```

I then tried to start a python3 session in my Terminal, and I could execute `import cv2` successfully without any errors. However, when I tried to execute `import cv2` in Visual Studio Code, I get the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "motiondetector.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import cv2
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
> ```

I also get the same error when I am running my code on IDLE.

Does anyone know why this errror occurs? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your Python interpreter path for vscode https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment  then use `which python3` to find the path and set the pythonpath in Vscode to that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer - I had to install the `OpenCV` module in the IDE as well! Thank you to everyone who helped! :)